# Checkear solo los checkbox visibles

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo el siguiente código en javascript donde selecciono los checkbox en una tabla

```js
function checkAll(ele) {
  //Obtener todos los checkbox que estan visibles;
  var checkboxes = $(':checkbox:visible');
  var celdas = $('#table tbody > tr').find('td');
  var status = $(celdas[7]).html();

  if (ele.checked) {
    //Recorro todos los checkbox y los voy seleccionando
    checkboxes.each(function(index, input){
       input.checked=true;
    });
  } else {
       //Recorro todos los checkbox y los voy deseleccionando
      checkboxes.each(function(index, input){
        input.checked=false;
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table id="table" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Task</th>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" onchange="checkAll(this)" id="selectAll"></th> 
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>001</td>
  <td>Item2</td>
  <td><input class="form-check-input" id="Escoge1" name="Escoge" type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>002</td>
  <td>Item1</td>
  <td><input class="form-check-input" id="Escoge2" name="Escoge" type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
    <tr style="display: none;">
  <td>3</td>
  <td>003</td>
  <td>Item3</td>
  <td><input class="form-check-input" id="Escoge3"  name="Escoge" type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Aparte estoy utilizando una liberia en Jquery [ddtf.js](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-jQuery-Dropdown-Table-Filter-Plugin-ddtf-js/), lo que realiza me filtra los campos de una tabla. Esta Liberia filtra agregando el css style  `display : none`.

Pero si filtro y  selecciono el checkbox que me selecciona el resto de los checkbox este igual me selecciona los checkbox escondidos.

Como puedo agregar una condición que me seleccione solos los que esta visibles en mi tabla?

Comment: puedes validar los checkbox con el método de jquery $(".checkbox").is(":visible"); esto te devolverá true/false.

Comment: @MerlingSamuelSobalvarro la libreria me agrega el `display:none` al `tr` no al input

Comment: igual te puede funcionar :)

Comment: si son input type="checkbox" con $(':checkbox:visible') puedes hacerlo

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas algo asi ` $(':checkbox:visible').prop('checked', true);` en un if ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta con esto:

```
function checkAll(ele) {
  //Obtener todos los checkbox que estan visibles;
  var checkboxes = $(':checkbox:visible');
  var celdas = $('#tableDespacho tbody > tr').find('td');
  var status = $(celdas[7]).html();

  if (ele.checked) {
    //Recorro todos los checkbox y los voy seleccionando
    checkboxes.each(function(index, input){
        $(input).attr('checked', true); 
    });
  } else {
       //Recorro todos los checkbox y los voy deseleccionando
      checkboxes.each(function(index, input){
        $(input).removeAttr('checked'); 
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: funciono muy bien gracias!.

Comment: ;) no hay de que

Comment: Tengo la siguiente duda al seleccionar una vez me lo marcan todos, pero si los desmarco y los vuelvo a marcarlos todos no funciona :( edite el codigo

Comment: Cuando dices que vuelves a marcarlos todos es a traves del checkbox con id checkAll o uno a uno???

Comment: primero los marco todos despues los desmarco, pero quiero volver a marcarlos todos y no puedo. Pero puedo marcar de a uno en uno

Comment: intenta cambiar $(input).attr('checked', true) por input.checked=true; y $(input).removeAttr por input.removeAttribute('checked') y me dices

Comment: @mira mi snippet `TypeError: $(...).removeAttribute is not a function`

Comment: es sin el $() esa funcion es de javascript no de jquery por eso es input.removeAttribute en vez de $(input).removeAttribute